# Nest Js not building monorepo on generate app command nothing is chaning in my code directory

Tags: nestjs, monorepo

i used command **nest new newstack** it created a project directory for me but according to monorepo documentation if we use execute **nest generate app app-name** inside the project created by the initial command then it automatically switches the project structure to monorepo but the command **nest generate app app-name** has no effect on my project created though its not throwing any error

i went through following docs

1. https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#monorepo-mode
2. https://medium.com/@exfabrica/nestjs-installation-and-creation-of-a-monorepo-project-with-cqrs-architecture-9bab1516f6d0
   both have shown the same method

Answer (score 0):

the issue was because of older version of [@nestjs/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/cli) i updated it to the latest version and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this case before, so I resolved it as follows.

```
 1. nest new newstack
 2. npm install -g @nestjs/cli or yarn global add @nestjs/cli (again)
 3. nest generate app app-name
```

Note: Let's make sure to pay attention to this nest-cli.json file.

If you find my assistance useful, I would greatly appreciate it if you could leave a positive review or rating. It helps me know that I'm providing valuable assistance and it also helps other users who may be looking for similar help. Thank you!